# Do I need to prepare anything for the upcoming homestead release?

Tags: clients, homestead, forks, upgrading

This is a canonical question. What actions should

- regular users
- miners and pool operators
- developers

undertake to prepare for the upcoming homestead release which includes a forking mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a community wiki. If releases of other clients are available, please edit the list below.

#### EVERYONE: Update clients!

- Upgrade geth nodes at least to [version 1.3.5](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.3.5)
- Upgrade ++eth nodes to at least [version 1.2.2](https://github.com/ethereum/webthree-umbrella/releases/tag/v1.2.2)
- Upgrade mist browser to at least [version 0.5.1](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.5.1)
- Upgrade parity nodes to at least [version 0.9.1](https://github.com/ethcore/parity/releases/tag/beta-0.9.1)
- Upgrade ethereumj nodes to at least [version 1.2.0](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/releases/tag/1.2.0-homestead-RC)

#### What changes are included?

Primarily protocol changes not affecting the end user:

- [EIP-2](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-2.mediawiki): Main homestead hardfork changes
- [EIP-7](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-7.md): Hardfork EVM update: DELEGATECALL
- [EIP-8](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-8.md): devp2p forward compatibility

#### What changes should developers know about?

- Block time changes (do not rely on average block time in contract code)
- New `DELEGATECALL` opcode
- Block gas limit increased from 3141592 to 4712388 (~50% increase)
- Default gas price reduced from 50 shannon to 20 shannon (~60% reduction)

Answer (score -1):

Read [Homestead Release FAQ](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/48arax/homestead_release_faq/) on [Reddit Ethereum](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/).

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers.