# Mac [El Capitan], Mist is stuck on block 1,150,006

Tags: mist, synchronization, homestead, mac-osx

I'm on a Mac with El Capitan and am running the latest version of Mist.It's stuck on block 1,150,006 and I'm not sure why neither do I know what to do...

[image: Mist is stuck...]

Answer (score 8):

#### 1) Double Check Mist Version

You are on an outdated version of mist. Upgrade [to 0.5.2](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/tag/0.5.2) or later.

There was a hard fork on block 1,150,000 - referred to as the *homestead* release. Read more on this:

- [Ethereum blog](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/02/29/homestead-release/).
- [Reddit r/ethereum](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/48arax/homestead_release_faq/).
- [Ethereum Stack Exchange](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1687/87).

#### 2) Reset the blockchain

If you are on the latest version of mist but still stuck, reset your blockchain.

Find your ethereum blockchain files. You are usually using `geth` which was included with the mist release. Try removing:

```
~/Library/Ethereum/chaindata
```

And start mist again. Now you will have to resync the whole chain but it should not get stuck at the Homestead fork. (1,150,006 is the latest Frontier block by the way.)

Comment: For step2, since reset the blockchain will take time, if you want to try something advanced, try step1.5 in a Geth console with `debug.setHead(1150000)` https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Go-ethereum-management-API's#debug and restart Mist.

Answer (score 6):

Check to verify that you indeed using the latest version of Mist.

If you are 100% sure, reboot your computer and try again.

- [Github Issue #363 - Stuck Sync El Capitan](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/362)
- [Github Issue #338 - Stuck Sync El Capitan 2](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/issues/388)

Answer (score 1):

Just start geth on its own

```
/Application/Mist.app/Contents/Framework/node/geth/geth
```

then start the Mist.app, it will connect to the already running geth instance.

I don't know why but if you use Mist Application alone it always get stuck during blocks download

Answer (score 1):

One reason could be that you are running `geth` command line tool when starting Mist, preventing Mist to launch/connect to its internal `geth` properly.